# In Java spark, how to select columns based on index

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

how can i only select 2nd and 5th column from a csv file (no column name in file) in java spark, code as below:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = getSparkSession().get().read()
                .option("delimiter", "|")
                .option("header", false)
                .csv(fileName);
```

Comment: If you read the file like that, then `_c1` and `_c4` are second and fifth column respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the schema by below command:

```
dataset.printSchema();
```

after that select the column you want

`dataset.select("c1",c4");`